# Soundcloud custom player passing info from other frame

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am using the SoundCloud custom player (https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player) and have a site where this needs to be in a seperate frame so the audio keeps playing when the main site is being navigated. I need to pass the track url to the player in the top frame from within the main frame. I have tried the below code with no luck. The top frame has the name and id of 'play'. Can anyone advise how I can do this please? Many thanks.

```
<a class="sc-remote-play" href="#">Play Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('a.sc-remote-play').live('click', function(event) {
  $('top.frames["play"].sc-player').scPlayer({
  links: [{url: "http://SOUNDCLOUD_PATH_HERE"}],
  autoPlay: true
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parent.frames` to get the other frame. [This Page](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/index.html?page=7) gives a description of how to work with frames.

You can use `parent.frames[0]` to get to the window of the first frame. To find an element on there with jQuery, you need to give it a context like:

```
$('.sc-player', parent.frames[0].document)
```

However, this means that you'll have two pieces of code playing music that don't know about each other. I think it's better for you to create a function that plays, and allow the other frame to use it. The player code will be like this:

```
play = function(url) {
  $('.sc-player').scPlayer({
    links: [{url: url}], autoPlay: true
  });
};
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click','a.sc-playme1', function(event) {
  play("http://soundcloud.com/axwell/cotu-dyrormx-dannyhoward");
 });
 $(document).on('click','a.sc-playme2', function(event) {
  play("http://soundcloud.com/vatogonzalez/earthquakeremix");
 });
});
```

The site code will then call it through `parent.frames[0]`:

```
$(document).on('click','a.sc-playme4', function(event) {
  parent.frames[0].play("http://soundcloud.com/vatogonzalez/earthquakeremix");
});
```

Here's a plunker showing it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/AvlipjpPvE7x15CstAiU?p=preview
Play Me 4 is the one that works. Play Me 3 doesn't work right. Hit Play Me 3 and any other link to see that they both play simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried   $('parent.frames[0].sc-player').scPlayer({ and   $('parent.play.sc-player').scPlayer({ but no luck, have I missed something silly?

Comment: @TimMellson Did you verify that parent.frames[0] is actually the right frame, and has the stuff you need? It would be good to ask the browser what it thinks is in there.

Comment: Yes I checked with Firebug and [0] is correct and I believe it has everything I need. I've put some simplified code online at http://www.greenbliss.co.uk/index2.htm, the top frame has the player where I want it and two test links that play fine but they need to work in the bottom frame.

Comment: @TimMellson I've updated my answer with more details on how you can use parent.frames with jQuery and your example problem.